# 構造体Binding時のデザイナ挙動について

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Windows10 Pro [1909] OSビルド 18363.720
VisualStudio Community 2019 [Ver 16.5.2]
.NetFramework 4.8.03752

---

WPFの構造についての質問です。

現在、カスタムコントロールを作成しているのですが
自作の構造体型の依存関係プロパティを持ったオブジェクトがあります。
これをカスタムコントロールのTemplate内からBindingしており
実行時にも想定通り動作します。

しかし、分からないのはこのカスタムコントロールを使用する側のデザイナ実行時の挙動で、
依存関係プロパティに値を設定しても即時反映されません。

もう少し詳しく言うと、Name, Item, Remarkという3つのobjectを持てるコントロールで
それぞれをGridの左、中、右に配置されるようなコントロールになります。
Xamlは以下の通りです。

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ItemSet}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ItemSet}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ItemNameColumn"
                                                  Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:ItemSet}, Path=GridDefinitions.First}"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="ItemColumn"
                                                  Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:ItemSet}, Path=GridDefinitions.Second}"/>
                                <ColumnDefinition x:Name="RemarkColumn"
                                                  Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=local:ItemSet}, Path=GridDefinitions.Third}"/>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="0" Content="{TemplateBinding ItemName}"/>

                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="1" Content="{TemplateBinding Item}"/>

                            <ContentPresenter Grid.Column="2" Content="{TemplateBinding Remark}"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

そしてコード側

```
    [ContentProperty(nameof(Item))]
    public class ItemSet : ContentControl
    {
        static ItemSet()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ItemSet), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ItemSet)));
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemNameProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "ItemName",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(ItemSet),
                new PropertyMetadata());

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Item",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(ItemSet),
                new PropertyMetadata());

        public static readonly DependencyProperty RemarkProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "Remark",
                typeof(object),
                typeof(ItemSet),
                new PropertyMetadata());

        public static readonly DependencyProperty GridDefinitionsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register(
                "GridDefinitions",
                typeof(Definitions),
                typeof(ItemSet),
                new PropertyMetadata());


        public object ItemName
        {
            get => GetValue(ItemNameProperty);
            set => SetValue(ItemNameProperty, value);
        }

        public object Item
        {
            get => GetValue(ItemProperty);
            set => SetValue(ItemProperty, value);
        }

        public object Remark
        {
            get => GetValue(RemarkProperty);
            set => SetValue(RemarkProperty, value);
        }

        public Definitions GridDefinitions
        {
            get => (Definitions)GetValue(GridDefinitionsProperty);
            set => SetValue(GridDefinitionsProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

やりたいことはGridDefinitionsプロパティ値に応じて
3つのカラムの幅を変更するというものです。

例えば、使用側から「1*,2*,3*」という風に指定した場合
それぞれのカラムのWidthプロパティにカンマ区切りの値が適用されます。

Definitions構造体とTypeConverterは以下の通り定義しています。

```
    [TypeConverter(typeof(DefinitionsTypeConverter))]
    public struct Definitions
    {
        public GridLength First { get; set; }
        public GridLength Second { get; set; }
        public GridLength Third { get; set; }

        public Definitions(GridLength first, GridLength second, GridLength third)
        {
            First = first;
            Second = second;
            Third = third;
        }
    }
```

```
public class DefinitionsTypeConverter : TypeConverter
    {
        public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
        {
            return sourceType == typeof(string);
        }

        public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, CultureInfo culture, object value)
        {
            var str = (string)value;
            var spl = str.Split(',');
            var ary = spl
                .Select(x =>
                {
                    if (x == "Auto")        return new GridLength(0, GridUnitType.Auto);
                    if (x.Last() == '*')    return new GridLength(double.Parse(x.Substring(0, x.Length - 1)), GridUnitType.Star);
                    else                    return new GridLength(double.Parse(x), GridUnitType.Pixel);
                })
                .ToArray();
            return new Definitions(ary[0], ary[1], ary[2]);
        }
    }
```

この状態で使用側から先ほどの例と同じ値を指定した時、
ビルド直後はデザイナ上「1*,1*,1*」の状態で表示されます。
しかし、このうちひとつの値を変更した時、値が反映され、
それぞれの割合で表示されるようになります。

もちろん、ビルドは正常に通っており、実行時は想定通りの動作をするのですが
なぜデザイン時にこのような挙動になってしまうのでしょうか。

プロパティの方が構造体であることが原因かとも思いましたが
例えばThisckness構造体であるMarginプロパティでは
このような現象がおこりませんし、どのような構造になっているのか気になっています。

色々と知識不足であるとは思いますが、ご教示いただければと思います。

Comment: 問題の再現手順の詳細が欲しいです。`<local:ItemSet ItemName="AAA" Item="BBB" Remark="CCC" GridDefinitions="1*,2*,3*" />`で表示してみましたが、デザイナ上でもとくに問題なく表示されてるように見えました。

Comment: @nee 試していただいてありがとうございます。現象が起きたのはGridDefinitions指定後、ビルドして実行、プログラム終了して再度デザイナを開いた時に発生しています。しかし、その後さらにGridDefinitionsの値を変更すると正しく反映されるという状態です。理想はデザイナに戻った時の初期表示から値が適用された状態になっていてほしいというものです。何かのバグでしょうか…？

Comment: 手順を試してみましたが現象を再現できませんでした。環境依存かもしれませんので、WndowsやVisualStudio、.NETFrameworkのバージョンの情報もあると回答が得られやすいかもしれません。「編集」で質問文を編集できますのでそちらに記載されると良いかと思います。

Comment: 問題の症状で「1*,1*,1*」の状態になるとありますが、仮にTypeConverterが機能していなかったとしたら初期値「Auto,Auto,Auto」になると思います。こちら間違いないでしょうか。なにかが「1*,1*,1*」を設定している可能性はありますか？

Comment: 使用するアプリ側のソース(Designer.csも含めて)も追記してみるとか、VS2019の最新は16.5.2なので上げてみるとかはどうでしょう？

Comment: @nee
問題の症状で「1*,1*,1*」になったのは数値で確認出来ていた訳ではないので、確かに「Auto,Auto,Auto」だった可能性があります。使用側でコンテンツに設定していたものがたまたま1*,1*,1*に近かった為そう思い込んでしまいました。
ただ、VS2019のバージョンを最新にしてみたところ、今のところ症状が発生しなくなりました。実行後もデザイナ上で正常に表示されます。しかし、今度は実行時にGridDefinitionsの適用がワンテンポ遅れる様になりました。画面表示後、0.1秒程ですが体感できるくらいの時差です。カスタムコントロールの作り方が良くないのでしょうか。

Comment: @kunif 回答ありがとうございます。VS2019のバージョンを最新にしてみたところ、今のところ症状が発生しなくなりました。実行後もデザイナ上で正常に表示されます。しかし、今度は実行時にGridDefinitionsの適用がワンテンポ遅れる様になりました。画面表示後、0.1秒程ですが体感できるくらいの時差です。カスタムコントロールの作り方が良くないのでしょうか。

Comment: この辺のツール類をどうにかしてボトルネック等を調べてみてはどうでしょう？ [Visual Studio でアプリのパフォーマンスを測定する](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/visualstudio/profiling/?view=vs-2019)

Comment: 問題が変化してきているように感じますので、質問文の修正をおすすめします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

おそらくですが、`TemplateBinding`と`Binding`の反映タイミングの違いによる現象かと思われます。ColumnDefinitionへの反映が遅れるため、ColumnDefinitionの初期値の「1*」で表示される時間があるように思えます。

解決策として思いつくのは

- バインドを`TemplateBinding`で統一する
- カスタムコントロールを UserControl で作り直し、ControlTemplateを使わない作りにする

といったところでしょうか。